# Magento error : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded;

Tags: mysql, innodb, magento-1.9

i have the following problem and i dont know how to solve it. Frontend and Backend dont work. Has anyone an idear ?

```html
a:5:{i:0;s:458:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `catalogrule` SET `name` = ?, `description` = ?, `from_date` = ?, `to_date` = '2017-07-30', `is_active` = ?, `conditions_serialized` = ?, `actions_serialized` = ?, `stop_rules_processing` = ?, `sort_order` = ?, `simple_action` = ?, `discount_amount` = ?, `sub_is_enable` = ?, `sub_simple_action` = ?, `sub_discount_amount` = ? WHERE (rule_id='17')";i:1;s:3033:"#0 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#4 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#5 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(635): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#6 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(433): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('catalogrule', Array, 'rule_id='17'')
#7 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule))
#8 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/local/Mirasvit/Action/Model/Observer.php(51): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/local/Mirasvit/Action/Model/Observer.php(24): Mirasvit_Action_Model_Observer->updateStatus()
#10 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Mirasvit_Action_Model_Observer->onControllerActionLayoutRenderBefore(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mirasvit_Action_Model_Observer), 'onControllerAct...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(384): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...')
#14 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php(82): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#15 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction()
#16 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#17 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /is/htdocs/wp1158418_XAIH5ALR0L/www/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}";s:3:"url";s:17:"/index.php/admin/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Please show the code of the statement you're trying to execute.

Comment: You have a long-running query on a big table; let's fix that.

Comment: Or you started a transaction and forgot to `COMMIT`/`ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score 2):

When externol script is running its apply changes in database for
multiple time, Because of this mysql services is stack. Due to this reason
website stopped working. Then you can changes the innodb lock wait timeout
setting in php.ini file.

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=5000
```

Comment: Increasing that will only cause other troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Cache

Follow below directory,

var/cache

The problem will be resolved.